# Number of PCIe Lanes supported by processor - how many/which devices are still usable? (i5 6600K)

Tags: graphics-card, cpu, motherboard, pci-express

I'm planning on getting the Intel i5 6600K which, according to Intel, [supports 16 PCIe Lanes max](http://ark.intel.com/products/88191/Intel-Core-i5-6600K-Processor-6M-Cache-up-to-3_90-GHz).

Now, I've searched around a bit, (also read through some forums, but they weren't too clear) and according to [Linus' benchmarks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rctaLgK5stA), it's not a performance issue to tune down on one lane a bit. However, at the end of the video (about 6:40) he says that in configurations that use other PCIe devices, some lanes might actually be *disabled*.

Here's the minimum of PCIe devices I'm gonna use:

1 Asus Xonar DGX Soundcard (PCIe x1), 1 decent GPU (PCIe x16), 1 WiFi card (PCIe x1)

Now, it's obvious that the GPU will only use an x8 Lane at best, since the CPU supports no more than 16. As I said, that's not a problem at all - what I'm wondering, is there a possibility that one of my other devices will be completely disabled? or, say, i want to use yet another device (i.e. a PCIe x4 device), and that won't work?

I don't quite get how those things are handled, but it doesn't seem as if the mere sum of used PCIe lanes reflects how the CPU distributes them - or does it?

PS: If it is relevent, MoBo is gonna be the MSI B150 PC-Mate.

Comment: How many entirely depend on the mtherboard.

Comment: @Ramhound do you mean the physical lanes available on the Motherboard or the support from the chipset?

Comment: Both actually.  I am to busy to pull out the Intel image that explains the PCI_E lanes.  I already wrote an answer once before don't feel like doing it again.